# What's the relationship between "seesaw" and "see" & "saw"

Tags: word-meaning

Recently, I found the word "seesaw" can separate to "see" and "saw", which "saw" is past tense of "see"

But I wonder why the two same meaning of word "see" & "saw" can become a balance equipment named "seesaw"

Does it have some allusion? Or just a coincident?

Comment: Etymology online is a useful resource to check first https://www.etymonline.com/word/see-saw

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Also https://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-see2.htm

Comment: The ***see*** in ***seesaw*** has nothing to do with ***sight, vision***. It's just an example of ***reduplication*** - with ***saw***, which probably *does* have etymological significance here (because it alludes to the way a saw-blade goes back-and-forth or up-and-down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oxford Dictionaries gives the derivation as:

*mid 17th century (originally used by sawyers as a rhythmical refrain): reduplication of the verb saw (symbolic of the sawing motion).*

Before mechanisation, logs of wood had to be cut up by two men, each holding one end of a long saw and pulling it to and fro. Apparently "See-saw" was a chant they used as they worked, and the meaning was extended to the children's toy with its up-and-down movement.